Ubuntu 24.04 freezes at various times and even reboots
Good evening, everyone!
I am completely in a fit because my computer is really giving me rough moments. The screen hangs sometimes, while at other times, it restarts itself.
In the beginning, I thought it was an error in my installation of Ubuntu. All this while, I was using Windows with this machine; after migration, I installed 24.10 Ubuntu. To try and fix the issue, I did a clean install with 24.04.05 LTS. Also, according to the availability of the manufacturer's specifications, I have been updating each and every driver; the issue stands unaffected.
As a last resort, I modified the GRUB configurations and added the following parameters to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: quiet splash kernel.watchdog=1 kernel.soft_watchdog=1 nmi_watchdog=1. But the behavior has not changed.
Right now, I have passed all the ideas that I could come up with. Anyone who went through this experience or can help me discover a few things will be highly.
System Configuration:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5700X (PBO enabled)
GPU: ASUS TUF Gaming Radeon™ RX 6700 XT OC
Motherboard: SY-YL B550M
RAM: 32GB (XMP Profile enabled)

Notes: CPU: 20% on regular usage, less than 40% for memory. Everything's stable and normal in temperature. I faced an identical problem under Windows whereby the screen flickered randomly. The problem could only be solved after using MorePowerTool utility alone with a modified GPU ROM with GFXOFF disabled. Only after this did the symptoms cease to exist. Thank you in advance for assistance in this matter!

This sounds like it would be a hardware problem, like the power source failing to supply enough power. Which brings me to the question, is it a laptop or a desktop?

It's a desktop. My power supply is a Gigabyte P650B 650W. I don't believe that this is the problem, given that in Windows after disabling the feature of GFXOFF worked perfectly and so stayed for a year. This week I decided to switch to Ubuntu but simply do not know how to solve.

You don’t seem to have this problem directly but might be worth testing.  There appears to be an incompatibility between Wayland and some Nvidia drivers – you have an AMD video card but may be worth trying.
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE  ==>  should output either ‘wayland’ or 11’
Switch this file to the opposite:

Open /etc/gdm3/custom.conf as root
Uncomment the line #WaylandEnable=false by removing the #
Save the file
Reboot

Uncommenting will switch back to X11, commenting will enable Wayland.  From what I’ve read some systems running X11 poorly will be corrected by switching to Wayland.  (Source:
UBUNTU 24.04LTS stops working several times all of a sudden!  )
Good Luck!
Barry

Thanks a lot, Barry! I just applied this config on my computer, and I'll see if this annoying problem disappears.
